# execute javascript function using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I am trying to execute a javascript function using VBA but without success.

I select an item in the list box.

**My goal:** refresh the result after item selected.

**VBA:**

```
IEdoc_NEW2.getElementById("native_dropdown_selected_size_name").selectedIndex = 1
Call IEdoc_NEW2.parentWindow.execScript("dummySubmitButton()", "JavaScript")
```

**HTML:**

```html
<select name="dropdown_selected_size_name" tabindex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown" id="native_dropdown_selected_size_name" autocomplete="off" data-a-touch-header="Taille">
  <option id="native_size_name_-1" value="-1" selected="" data-a-id="size_name_-1">Sélectionner</option>
  <option class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_0" value="0,B07DHJZSB3" data-a-id="size_name_0" data-a-html-content="S" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable">
    S </option>
  <option class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_name_1" value="1,B07DHKZM7P" data-a-id="size_name_1" data-a-html-content="M" data-a-css-class="dropdownUnavailable">
    M
  </option>
  <option class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_name_2" value="2,B07DHK697N" data-a-id="size_name_2" data-a-html-content="L" data-a-css-class="dropdownUnavailable">
    L
  </option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
if (typeof(TwisterNonJs) == 'undefined') {
  window.TwisterNonJs = {};
  TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown = [];
}
TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown[1] = function() {
  var twisterUpdateButton = "submit.twisterUpdateButton_1"
  document.getElementById("dummySubmitButton").setAttribute("name", twisterUpdateButton);
  document.forms['twister'].submit();
};
document.getElementById("native_dropdown_selected_size_name").onchange = function() {
  TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown[1]();
};
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try onchange fireEvent

```
IEdoc_NEW2.getElementById("native_dropdown_selected_size_name").FireEvent "onchange"
```

You could also try adding an event then firing it

```
Dim evt As Object
Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False

IEdoc_NEW2.querySelector("#native_dropdown_selected_size_name").dispatchEvent evt
```