# Value not getting updated in IE when trying to change it using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to change the drop down value of a field in IE using VBA but the value is not getting updated in IE.

Below is my code:

```
IE.Document.getelementbyid("ddlSchemeCategory").Value = "MANAGE CASH"
Set objButton = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ddlSchemeCategory")
objButton.Focus
objButton.Click
```

HTML Code for the field I am trying to change:

```
<div class="selectbg">
  <div class="selectedvalue" id="divscat">All Categories</div>
    <select name="ddlSchemeCategory" tabindex="4" class="ddlSchemeCategory" id="ddlSchemeCategory" style="display: inline-block;">
      <option value="-1">All Categories</option>
      <option value="CREATE WEALTH">CREATE WEALTH</option>
      <option value="MANAGE CASH">MANAGE CASH</option>
      <option value="NFO">NFO</option>
      <option value="STABLE INCOME">STABLE INCOME</option>
      <option value="RETIREMENT">RETIREMENT</option>
      <option value="SAVE TAX">SAVE TAX</option>
    </select>                              
</div>
```

I have also tried using SelectIndex but that also did not workout for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try these options below:

```
Sub firstOption()


Dim slct As HTMLSelectElement
Set slct = ie.document.getElementById("ddlSchemeCategory")
Dim opt


For Each opt In slct.getElementsBytagname("option")
    If opt.Value = "CREATE WEALTH" Then 'CREATE WEALTH sample value to be selected
        opt.Selected = True
        slct.fireevent "onchange"
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

End Sub


Sub secondOption()


Dim slct As HTMLSelectElement
Set slct = ie.document.getElementById("ddlSchemeCategory")
Dim opt

Dim evt
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
For Each opt In slct.getElementsBytagname("option")
    If opt.Value = "CREATE WEALTH" Then
        opt.Selected = True
        slct.dispatchEvent evt
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks so much, option 2 worked for me as well. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

you can try make the change with attribute = value selector for the options and then FireEvent. You might also consider attaching a [change event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091264/6241235) to the `select` element.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='CREATE WEALTH']").Selected = True
ie.document.querySelector("#ddlSchemeCategory").FireEvent "onchange"
```