# Elements not able to select on Webpage-VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am fetching data from the following website:

https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/bhavcopy

There are 5 Filterable Fields as per below:

```
INSTRUMENT | COMMODITY | EXPIRY | FROM DATE | TO DATE
```

Field `EXPIRY` is blank by default. If we select `COMMODITY` then `EXPIRY` Field Dropdown Appears

I wanted to display data as per below Screenshot

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Download()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/bhavcopy"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[Class='today']").Click
            .getElementById("ddlInstrument").Value = "FUTCOM"
            .getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Focus
            .getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Value = "ALUMINI"
            .getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Click
            .getElementById("ddlExpiry").Value = "30AUG2019"
            .getElementById("ddlExpiry").Focus
            .getElementById("txtFromDate").Focus
            .getElementById("txtFromDate").Value = "01/08/2019"
            .getElementById("txtToDate").Focus
            .getElementById("txtToDate").Value = "07/08/2019"

            .querySelector("[id='btnShowCommoditywise']").Click


        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Field `EXPIRY` is not fetching automatically when I select `COMMODITY`

```
.getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Focus
                .getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Value = ALUMINI"
                .getElementById("ctl00_cph_InnerContainerRight_C001_ddlSymbols_Input").Click
```

Also Selecting Date as per my method shows an error: `Please Select From Date`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing into the field? I suspect, by setting the value, **OnChange** is not being triggered

Comment: You need to create and attach a change event to the instrument dropdown and dispatch that event after changing the value. For the next drop down there are a host of events associated with both the parent div and child input - so I suspect some combination and ordering of those is required. There is however a xhr POST request made by the page for the data which returns json. I can't get it to work with VBA for some reason (I think to do with the encoding of body), though the essentially the same request with python works just fine.

Comment: @Qharr Can you guide me How can I create and attach a change event to instrument Drop down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091264/6241235 when you correctly attach and fire on the first dropdown you will notice select expiry appears in third. When you correctly have the entry registered in the 2nd dropdown the dates will appear in the third.