# How do I interact with this Internet Explorer Dropdown ComboBox Navigation using VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am having difficulty trying to automate a dropdown comboBox in internet explorer using an Excel Macro. Note that I am very new to VBA language and web scraping.

The code I am using unsuccessfully is:

```
'Change Posting Period

Dim posting As Object
Set posting = ie.Document.getElementById("inpt_postingperiod2")
posting.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RMA").Range("C5").Value

'The value in this cell C5 in this instance is: Aug 2019
```

In internet explorer, this code will change the text that is displayed in the dropdown box but when I later submit the page, the underlying value was never really changed.

I tried adding the fireevents to the code such as:

```
posting.fireevent ("onfocus")
posting.fireevent ("onkeydown")
```

with no success

The script related to the dropdown is:

```html
<input name="inpt_postingperiod" title="Sep 2019" class="dropdownInput textbox uir-field-active" id="inpt_postingperiod2" role="combobox" aria-labelledby="postingperiod_fs_lbl" style="width: 280px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" contenteditable="false" onkeydown="getDropdown(this).handleKeydown(event);" onkeypress="getDropdown(this).handleKeypress(event);" onfocus="getDropdown(this).handleOnFocus(event);" onblur="getDropdown(this).handleOnBlur(event);" type="text" value="Sep 2019" autocomplete="off">
```

And the script for the dropdown option items:

```html
<div class="ns-dropdown" style="display: none;" data-name="postingperiod" data-settings='{"flags":-2147483520,"width":280,"minWidth":280,"mandatory":true}' data-default-option="4" data-options='[{"value":"127","text":"May 2019"},{"value":"128","text":"Jun 2019"},{"value":"129","text":"Jul 2019"},{"value":"131","text":"Aug 2019"},{"value":"132","text":"Sep 2019"},{"value":"133","text":"Oct 2019"},{"value":"138","text":"Nov 2019"},{"value":"139","text":"Dec 2019"},{"value":"140","text":"Jan 2020"},{"value":"142","text":"Feb 2020"},{"value":"143","text":"Mar 2020"},{"value":"144","text":"Apr 2020"}]' data-initialized="T">
</div>
```

Note that the Excel value of Aug 2019 should be selected from the dropdown options list. Thus, in order to automate this, I cannot use the value/index number since this will change in the future; I need to match the excel cell value of MMM YYYY to the MMM YYYY in the dropdown list (in this example Aug 2019).

Thank you for all the help!

Full code should be:

```html
<tr>

  <td>

<div class="uir-field-wrapper" data-field-type="select"><span id="postingperiod_fs_lbl_uir_label" class="smallgraytextnolink uir-label "><span id="postingperiod_fs_lbl" class="labelSpanEdit smallgraytextnolink" style="">

<a tabindex="-1" title="What's this?" href="javascript:void(&quot;help&quot;)" style="cursor:help" onclick="return nlFieldHelp('Field Help','postingperiod', 'TRAN_CUSTCRED_postingperiod_NA', this, 'EDIT_TRAN_CUSTCRED', '3905005', 'custcred', 136, 'creditmemo', 'T', '', 'Credit+Memo', 'APP:FORMLABEL:POSTING_PERIOD', '')" class="smallgraytextnolink" onmouseover="this.className='smallgraytext'; return true;" onmouseout="this.className='smallgraytextnolink'; ">Posting Period</a>
<img class="required_icon" title="Required Field" alt="Required Field" src="/images/chiles/pageTitle/required.png"><label class="uir-required-icon">*</label></span></span><span class="uir-field">
        <span id="postingperiod_fs" data-fieldtype="select" class="nldropdown" style="white-space:nowrap;" data-helperbutton-count="0"><div class="uir-select-input-container"><input name="inpt_postingperiod" type="text" value="Sep 2019" class="dropdownInput textbox" onkeydown="getDropdown(this).handleKeydown(event);" onkeypress="getDropdown(this).handleKeypress(event);" onfocus="getDropdown(this).handleOnFocus(event);" onblur="getDropdown(this).handleOnBlur(event);" aria-labelledby="postingperiod_fs_lbl" autocomplete="off" contenteditable="false" role="combobox" id="inpt_postingperiod2" title="Sep 2019" style="width: 280px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="ddarrowSpan">
 <img src="/uirefresh/img/field/dropdown.png" height="20" width="20" class="i_dropdownarrow" alt="More Options" id="inpt_postingperiod2_arrow">
</span></div>

<div class="ns-dropdown" data-name="postingperiod" data-initialized="T" data-options="[{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;127&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;May 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;128&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Jun 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;129&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Jul 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;131&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Aug 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;132&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Sep 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;133&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Oct 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;138&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Nov 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;139&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Dec 2019&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;140&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Jan 2020&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;142&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Feb 2020&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;143&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Mar 2020&quot;},{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;144&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Apr 2020&quot;}]" data-default-option="4" data-settings="{&quot;flags&quot;:-2147483520,&quot;width&quot;:280,&quot;minWidth&quot;:280,&quot;mandatory&quot;:true}" style="display: none; ">
</div>





<input name="postingperiod" type="hidden" class="nldropdown" value="132" onchange="this.isvalid=(nlapiValidateField(null,'postingperiod'));if (!this.isvalid) return false;if(!this.noslaving) { setWindowChanged(window, true); }if (Syncpostingperiod(true,null,null,null,null,null) == false) return false;if (getEventTarget(event)==this)this.focus();var kPeriod = nlapiGetFieldValue('postingperiod');
if (nlapiGetFieldValue('ppsetbyuser') != 'T' || kPeriod != nlapiGetFieldValue('ppsetbyuservalue')) {
 if ( nlapiGetField('postingperiod').noSlaving() || nlapiGetFieldValue('ppsetbyuser') == 'S' ) {
var kPeriod = nlapiGetFieldValue('postingperiod');
if (kPeriod &amp;&amp; typeof pp_ss !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; pp_ss[1132] !== undefined) {
 var iPeriod = + kPeriod + 1000;
 var bUseCurrent = (pp_ss[iPeriod] === undefined)
 if (!bUseCurrent) {
 var td = stringtodate(nlapiGetFieldValue('trandate'));
 var pp_s = stringtodate(pp_ss[iPeriod]);
 var pp_e = stringtodate(pp_es[iPeriod]);
 var cur_s = stringtodate(pp_es[1132]);
  bUseCurrent = !(pp_s <= td &amp;&amp; pp_e >= td) &amp;&amp; cur_s > pp_s;
 }
 if (bUseCurrent)
  nlapiSetFieldValue('postingperiod', 132, false);
}
nlapiSetFieldValue('ppsetbyuser', 'F', false);
nlapiSetFieldValue('ppsetbyuservalue', '', false);
 } else if (kPeriod) {
nlapiSetFieldValue('ppsetbyuser', 'T', false);
nlapiSetFieldValue('ppsetbyuservalue', nlapiGetFieldValue('postingperiod'), false);
 }
}
;nlapiFieldChanged(null,'postingperiod');" id="hddn_postingperiod2">

<input type="hidden" value="4" id="indx_postingperiod2">

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var win = (window.parentAccesible != false && parent.initializeDropdowns) ? parent : window;
        win.initializeDropdowns(win.NS.jQuery(document));
    }())
</script><span class="field_widget_helper_pos effectStatic"></span></span>
</span>
</div>
  </td>

    </tr>
```

Note, the dropdown options do not display because they are generated from a password protected website but the options are just dates in MMM YYYY format

I also tried:

```
Dim posting As Object
Set posting = ie.document.querySelector("#inpt_postingperiod2")
posting.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RMA").Range("C5").Value
posting.fireevent ("onchange")
```

with no success: I don't think changing the text value props the dropdown and makes a selection. You can see this when hovering over the dropdown.  Even though it says Aug 2019 it is actually Sept 2019:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZG5m.png)

Image showing dropdown not selected correctly before submission

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: the url requires a username and password but I just recently edited my post to include the full code for the dropdown.

Comment: try creating an html event as _change_ then after setting the value fire that event on ie.document.querySelector("#inpt_postingperiod2") see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091264/6241235)

Comment: If you look at my link it creates the event and dispatches it.

Comment: I tried this with no success:      [Dim posting As Object
Set posting = ie.document.querySelector("#inpt_postingperiod2")

posting.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RMA").Range("C5").Value
   posting.fireevent ("onchange")]           I think that because it is a dropdown, pasting text and the fireing an event does not find a match in the dropdown list!

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that it is using any event to set the selected value in drop down.

We can see that in your dropdown code there are many events like

```
onkeydown="getDropdown(this).handleKeydown(event);" onkeypress="getDropdown(this).handleKeypress(event);" onfocus="getDropdown(this).handleOnFocus(event);" onblur="getDropdown(this).handleOnBlur(event);"
```

So you can try to fire these events from your VBA code to check and verify that which event is changing and setting the value in dropdown.

You can fire event from VBA like below.

```
Element.FireEvent("onkeydown")
```

Your above code for dropdown is not generating the dropdown. If you provide the working dropdown code than we can try to test it and try to develop sample VBA code to set the value in it.

Comment: I tried the FireEvent with no success, not sure which element to fire it on! I also added the full code for the dropdown but the options are blocked (likely due to the fact that it is a password protected site)

Comment: You need to post a proper JS and CSS code for that combobox to work. If possible than try to create a similar kind of combo box by yourself in sample HTML page and post it here. It will be easier for us to make a test with it. you need to fire event on combobox element and you need to make a test with each event applied on that combobox to find the correct event which is setting the value in it.