# Call Javascript directly for 'click' button

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

i need to click on a 'button' where it does not have id , name 
it was a href into javascipt
..

Comment: Try execScript("callSearch();")? Not sure it would work, just seems like correct syntax. Thats some horrible html by the way.

Comment: is there an url to use?

Comment: Hi Lorne, indeed it was horrible...
hi QHarr. sorry cant share the URL because it's intranet. but that's almost the entire html code for that page

Comment: In "try1" does `a.click` actually execute?

Comment: @Tim. able to find the element, execute the click , but not responses

Comment: you could try [adding an click htmlEvent to the element then firing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090916/execute-javascript-function-using-vba/56091264#56091264).

Comment: Qharr . it does not work . not sure if i had coded it correctly . can help advice ? if it work then it will be useful before i also face similiar issue on other place where there is double click function without attribute, again ... here is the code i tried https://pastebin.com/tMbh5NhS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code, it seems that when we click the link, it will fire the JavaScript function:

```
Sub Main()
    'we define the essential variables

    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Dim ticket As String


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("<the website url>")

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set Data = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("appbut")

        Debug.Print Data.Length

        If Len(Data) > 0 Then
            For Each ee In Data

                Set link = ee.getElementsbyTagName("a")(0)
                ' it is better to check whether we could find the a tag.
                'check whether we could get the innertext.
                Debug.Print link.InnerText

                If link.InnerText Like "Cancel" Then

                    'click the link.
                    link.Click

                End If
            Next ee

        End If
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code in the web page:

```
<script>
    function callLookup() {
        alert("Party Search");
    };
    function callCancel() {
        alert("Cancel");
    };
    function callSearch() {
        alert("Search");
    }
</script>
<table  >
    <tr valign="bottom">
        <td colspan="5">
            <table  >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>

                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="appbut"><a href="javascript:callLookup();">Party Search</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="appbut"><a href="javascript:callCancel()">Cancel</a></td>
                        <td class="butspace"></td>
                        <td class="appbut"><a href="javascript:callSearch();">Search</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqIkv.gif).